# Merge blank cells in Interop

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, interop

I want to merge a range of 3 cells for each row where the first cell and the last cell are set to "", however it does not seem to work for me.

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 20;i++)
{
  string a = Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 4]);
  string b = Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 6]);

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
  {
    string c = worksheet.Cells[i, 5];
    worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[i , 4], worksheet.Cells[i + , 6]].Merge(1);
  
    /* currRange.Value2 = worksheet.Cells[i, 5];
      currRange.Select();
      currRange.Merge(Missing.Value);*/
  }
}
```

I tried doing it for all the rows whether the first and third cell are blank or not and it works.

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 20;i++)
{
  string c = worksheet.Cells[i, 5];
  worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[i , 4], worksheet.Cells[i , 6]].Merge(1);

  /* currRange.Value2 = worksheet.Cells[i, 5];
    currRange.Select();
    currRange.Merge(Missing.Value);*/
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `string c = Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 5].Value);` ?

Comment: The string c line is only meant to keep the value I'm adding to the merged columns

Comment: I meant trying it with all a, b and c .

Comment: I did try it out, but in vain. I'm sure I put each empty column's value as "", but whenever I  test it, it doesn't want

Comment: You can try other free libraries than interop, e.g. using `SpreadsheetLight` you can do something like `    for (int i = 2; i <= 20; i++)
    {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sl.GetCellValueAsString(i,4)))
     {
      sl.MergeWorksheetCells(i,4,i,6);
     }
    }`

Comment: Thank you, I've moved on to another part of the project, but I'll keep you posted whenever I come back and use SpreadsheetLight